# How to balance the data tasks in Apache IoTDB Version 1.0 when a new datanode is created?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I adds a new datanode in Apache IoTDB Version 1.0, will the previous data tasks be automaticaaly balanced to this datanode? If IoTDB does not balance the tasks automatically, can I manually order it to be balance to this node, and how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous data tasks will not be balanced to new nodes of Apache IoTDB, and it is best not to manually balance these tasks, for the process is complicated and may disrupt the existing balanced configuration. After a certain amount of data is newly written, it will be automatically stored on the new node of IoTDB.